# Unable to use the root user created in mogoDB bitnami helm charts installation

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes-helm

I used the below command with a valid flag to set the root user password explicitly. But when i try to login with those credentials the authentication fails with log saying - authentication fails.

Command  used:

```
helm install mongodb-test bitnami/mongodb --namespace test --set architecture=replicaset -- set replicaSet.enabled=true --set auth.rootPassword=password1! --set auth.username=admin -- set auth.password=password2! --set auth.database=poc
```

[image of `helm` command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaI0g.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

tried using root user login and expected to login successfully

Comment: Do the passwords need to be protected by quotes since they include `!`?